# exe stopped working after installing msi created using windows installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, active-directory, ldap, windows-installer

**I created a windows forms application and i created .msi from it using windows installer in visual studio 2010.When i install the .msi in windows 7,8 or even xp, the .exe is working well.But, when i install the same .msi in windows server 2012 R2 and run the ".exe" file.The windows shows "Application stopped working". But the Os has .net framework installed..**

```
Application has stopped Working
```

When i select show more details in the error popup. It shows Problem event Name :CLR20r3.Please someone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's caused by the .net framework or some other dependency. Check whether the windows server 2012 has the target .net framework installed. You can do this by going to visual studio => project => last option(literally the last option)  => Application,  there you'll see the target .net framework. to see which version of the .net framework is installed on the server to compare,  head over to this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed. 
Another solution would be installing the latest release of the microsoft 2005 backward compatibility. Good Luck!!

Comment: thnk u .. i missed installing visual c++ redistributible software.tats the main cause of the issue.